# How save object in Mongodb with scala

Tags: mongodb, scala

I have couple simple classes:

```
 class Address(street: String)
 class Person(name: String, addresses: List[Address])
```

How can I save it in MongoDB? And I want to use wrap/unwrap operation after saving operations.

When I try to use casbah API I have got the exception like this:

```
 MongoFactory.testCollection.save(Person("Name", List(Address("Street"))))

 Exception in thread "main"     org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: Can't find a codec for class mongo.MongoTest$Person2.
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo can use [ReactiveMongo](http://reactivemongo.org/) for this purpose. If you want to use `play-json` directly instead of `BSON`, you could use [ReactiveMongo play extension](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.11/documentation/tutorial/play2.html).

Comment: Does ReactiveMongo support custom classes or only case casses?

Comment: Yes,reactivemongo supports custom classes as well. In case of `custom classes`, you need to define `BSONDocument readers and writers` OR `json reads and writes`(for play extension) manually for each fields of class. In `case classes`, you could simply use `macros`.

Comment: Can I use save and find operations without manual mapping all fields of class to DBObject(BSON)? When I use java with popular ORM for mongoDB (spring data for example), I don't describe any readers or writers. If I have complicated object graph, it is so boring.

Comment: It is very sad that scala's mongoDB ORM doesn't support similar feature

Comment: You might be interested in [Mondrian](https://github.com/themillhousegroup/mondrian) (full disclosure: this is a personal project of mine). It uses Play's JSON support for case classes throughout so no additional mapping needed. It's been battle-tested in many production apps for over a year now.

Comment: @rdm why don't you use case classes ?